# Income Elasticity and Convexity of Demand in Income

Tags: consumer-theory, elasticity

What needs to be true about the demand function $z(y)$, where $y$ is income, for the income elasticity $\varepsilon = \frac{dz(y)}{dy}/\frac{z(y)}{y}$ to be always greater than one (so that the good is always a luxury)? In particular, does the demand function have to be convex in income? Would that be a sufficient condition?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for.

What you want may be technically feasible, but just barely. What I mean is that for any $\delta > 0$, you cannot have the income elasticity always be larger than $1 + \delta$. The simple reason is that it would mean that the amount spent on the good *always* increases faster than the income. Then eventually the amount spent on the good would just overtake the income, but this is, of course, a contradiction.

Income elasticity being exactly equal to one would be easy, e.g. demand derived from Cobb-Douglas.

You should also be able to construct a function $z(y)$ for which
$$
\epsilon(y) = 1 + \frac{1}{y},
$$
so that $\epsilon(y) > 1$, although 
$$
\lim_{y\to \infty} \epsilon(y) = 1.
$$
You would need to solve a differential equation:
\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{y} & = \frac{dz(y)}{dy}/\frac{z(y)}{y} \\
\\
z(y) \left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2}\right) & = \frac{dz(y)}{dy}.
\end{align*}
Unfortunately I am not good at these, so I don't know what $z$ yields a solution, but I don't think this is what you had in mind anyway.